# jQuery - access values after a find

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following line of javascript/jQuery:

```
var acct = e.container.find("input[name='CorrectedAccount']");
```

Logging the acct variable to console shows:

[image]

How do I access the value of accessKey?

Comment: It shows you in the debugger: `e.container.find("input[name='CorrectedAccount']")[0].accessKey`

Comment: either attr() or prop()

Comment: `prop('accessKey')`

Comment: Do you mind sharing what is `e.container`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

```
var acct = e.container.find("input[name='CorrectedAccount']");
console.log(acct[0].accessKey)
```

To get all accessKey you can use a loop

```
acct.each(function (index, input) {
    console.log(input.accessKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by passing the index 0

`var acct = e.container.find("input[name='CorrectedAccount']")[0].accessKey;`